# ProgressDialog hangs in asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

(I'm using 2.3.3)
The following code is an async task that puts up a progress dialog (pd), does an `HttpPost` in `doInBackground()`, and dismisses the progress dialog in `onPostExecute()`.  It works perfectly about 75% of the time.  But, 25% of the time the pd gets displayed and never goes away(the post gets done however).  The only way the user can get rid of the pd is to go into settings and kill the app (even though "cancelable is set to true").

A timeout exception is NOT happening.

`onPostExecute()` is not getting executed or the `pd.dismiss()` is not working.

If I eliminate the pd everything always works perfectly 100% of the time.

What an be happening? Thanks.

```java
class postStringToURLTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String> {
    String responseString = "";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        String myEmailAddress = getPref("emailaddress");
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(PSActivity.this, 
                                "Emailing Trip to " + myEmailAddress, "", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        try {
            URL onlyURL = urls[0];  //there is only one url
            HttpResponse response = null;
            HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams,4000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 4000);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(myParams);
            HttpPost myPost = new HttpPost(onlyURL.toString());
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(payloadString);
            myPost.setEntity(se);
            myPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            myPost.setHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
            response = httpclient.execute(myPost);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                          new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                responseString = line;
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            debugLog("postStringToURLTask got exception" + e.getMessage().toString() , 1); 
            responseString = "error  " + e.getMessage().toString();
        }        

        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pd.dismiss();
        debugLog("just dismissed progress dialog", 1);
        result = result.replace("[","");
        result = result.replace("\"","");
        result = result.replace("]","");

        ////log.w(getClass().getName(), "onPostExecute received: " + result);
        if (result == "") {
            mpGood.start();
        } else {
            sdTripSentProblem(); //bad news dialog
            logToServer(result);
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but instead of `result == ""`, do `if (result.length () == 0)` and never compare Strings with `==`

Comment: what context is pd defined in? Make sure it is a global variable or else you wont have access to dismiss it.  Everything eles looks ok

Comment: also, in general, I would make sure to check that the pd is showing before you try to dismiss it, as it can cause an error

Comment: follow the @Jameo comment and in post execute do this, if pd.isShowing(){pd.dismiss;}

Comment: made all of your suggested changes to no avail.  Got rid of PD and just put up toast and it works every time.  I think the truth is that the Android platform is a little flakey - at least at the 2.33 I am targeting.